# How to control the output archive path of maven assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

It seems like maven assembly plugin always output to ${project.dir}/target regardless of all the descriptor fields I set. Is this feature supported by maven assembly plugin?

Comment: can you show us your complete assembly descriptor and the POM, please?

Comment: Why would you like to locate the created archive somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course change that behaviour by using the correct configuration for [outputDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#outputDirectory) like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>TheLocationYouLike</outputDirectory>
    ..
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But i can't recommend that, cause it is against the convention over configuration paradigm.

Comment: the paradigm is "convention over configuration" ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right it turns out to be not in the config xml file